# Trying to resolve an interface implementation based on generic type passed at runtime in autofac

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I want to resolve a specific interface implementation from autofac based on the type of an input parameter passed at runtime.

In my code I have different implementations of `IMyTask<>`:

```
MySillyTask : IMyTask<SillyData>

MyAwesomeTask : IMyTask<AwesomeData>
```

I register the implementations of `MyTask<>` like this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof (IMyTask<>).Assembly)
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof (IMyTask<>));
```

I want use a class with an injected Autofac `IComponentContext` to resolve the data based on the type of Data passed:

```
public IMyTask<T> GetTask<T>(T input) where T : IData
{
  var myTask = _componentContext.Resolve<IMyTask<T>>(); // fails
  return myTask;
}
```

I get `The requested service has not been registered` error.

If I try to resolve it for a hardcoded `IData` type it works:

```
var myTask = _componentContext.Resolve<IMyTask<SillyData>>(); // works! MySillyTask resolved
```

I think it is because at runtime `T` is `IData` instead of the specific `IData` implementation I pass but is there a way to change the code to get the functionality I require?

EDIT:
As requested the complete error message:

```
The requested service 'Whatever.Tasks.IMyTask`1[[Whatever.Inputs.IData, Whatever, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
```

How I am calling `GetTask`:

```
 IData myData = input.MyData;
 taskResolver.GetTask(myData);
```

I think I realise it is because `T` is `IData` instead of an implementation that causes my code to fail. Though I have changed my code to use named instances and returning a non-generic 'IMyTask' I am still interested if I can use autofac to resolve it the way I originally intended.

Comment: Like this question.  Have you tried using an injected `Func<IMyTask<T>>` or `Func<Owned<IMyTask<T>>>`, where `T` is specified in the consuming class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about AutFac but I suppose `component.Resolve(...)` has an overload which accepts a type.

I sucessfully do something like this with Ninject

```
    public IMyTask GetTask<T>(T input) where T : IData
    {
        var taskType = typeof(IMyTask<>);
        var inputType = input.GetType();

        var genericType = taskType.MakeGenericType(inputType);
        return (IMyTask)_componentContext.Resolve(genericType);
    }
```

Comment: I changed `typeof(T)` to `input.GetType()` in your answer and this does exactly what I want to. Thanks.

Comment: Also I changed to return `IMyTask` instead of generic version. I can use T to derive which implementation to use but return a version where the calling code does not care about `T`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't supply the code that calls this, but I suspect the problem is that the type `T` is based on what you're calling code knows, not the actual type of `input`. If the calling code called it as `GetTask<SillyData>(obj);` I suspect it'd work but I assume your `obj` is a `IData` that just happens to be a `SillyData`.

If you need to call a generic method without knowing the Type in advance you'll have to use Reflection. You could use `input.GetType()` to get the real underlying type then use `MakeGenericType` to make the `ITask<SillyData>` then `MakeGenericMethod` to invoke `Resolve`.

Here's another stack overflow question that'll show you how to call a generic by passing a Type argument:

**[How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)**